# How can I combine two ranges in a bash loop?

Tags: bash

Hi I've searched and cannot find the answer. Maybe I wasn't using the right terms.

I know how to loop over numbers:

```
for x in {0..9}
do
```

But how can I loop over both numbers and alphabet, something like:

```
for x in {{0..9},{a..z}}
do
```

It works but seems to have a syntax error.

Comment: What kind of syntax error? I feel there is nothing wrong with your way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
for x in {0..9} {a..z}; do
```

I feel that yours is a correct way too, but if you are facing any syntax error, try the above format.

Comment: That works! My syntax error was that the second right curly bracket is said to be "literal". Can you tell me a little about when to use ; in Bash? I'm always confused. I can search first or open another question if follow-up question is not allowed. Many thanks!

Comment: ; in Bash is nothing but a line separator. Just like new line. In Bash, do is another command that's why i used a semi colon. I could have used a new line for do and it would have meant the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over Linux devices if you have more than 24 disks, you can use:

```
for D in {a..z} a{a..z}; do
      ls /dev/sd$D
done
```

and you iterate from sda to sdaz.